# JSONArray to Android ListView

Tags: android, json, listview

I am new to programming and my current app gets data from my server for a single data only and input it into textview. But now I have successfully created a php script that encodes JSONArray with multiple values but I dont know how to get the values to the android code via looping and I also dont know how to populate my listview.

**Sample JSON**

```
[{"lnumber":"2","violation":"2"},{"lnumber":"2","violation":"No Helmet"}]
```

**PHP Script**

```
$result = array();
$sql = "SELECT lnumber,violation FROM violators WHERE 
lnumber='".$lnumber."'";
$stmt = $con->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($lnumber, $violation);
while($stmt->fetch())
{
$temp = [
'lnumber'=>$lnumber,
'violation'=>$violation
];
array_push($result, $temp);
}
echo json_encode($result);
```

How am I currently getting data from server and displaying it using only textview.

**Android Code**

```
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            loading.dismiss();
            showJSON(response);
        }
    },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(getViolation.this,error.getMessage().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

}

private void showJSON(String response)
{
    try
    {
        String lnumber;
        String violation;
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
        JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray(getConfig.JSON_ARRAY);
        JSONObject violationData = result.getJSONObject(0);
        lnumber = violationData.getString(getConfig.KEY_LNUMBER);
        violation = violationData.getString(getConfig.KEY_VIOLATION);

        textViewResult.setText("License Number:\t"+lnumber+"\nViolation:\t"+violation);
    }
```

**PS:**
My Listview id is listView. If anyone can help me how to display multiple data from the server to the listview would be a very great help!

Answer (score 2):

> 1.Your `JSON` root tag is `[]` . You must use `JSONArray` . It is not `JSONObject` .
>
> 2.Your sample did not contain `datetime` key in your `JSONObject` .

Try this

**DataBean**

```
public class DataBean {

/**
 * lnumber : 2
 * violation : 2
 */

private String lnumber;
private String violation;

public String getLnumber() {
    return lnumber;
}

public void setLnumber(String lnumber) {
    this.lnumber = lnumber;
}

public String getViolation() {
    return violation;
}

public void setViolation(String violation) {
    this.violation = violation;
}
}
```

**Adapter**

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private List<DataBean> beanList;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private Context context;

    public MyAdapter() {
    }

    public MyAdapter(List<DataBean> beanList, Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        this.beanList = beanList;
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return beanList == null ? 0 : beanList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return beanList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout, null);
        DataBean dataBean = beanList.get(position);
        text.setText(dataBean.getLnumber() + dataBean.getViolation());
        return view;
    }
}
```

**Activity**

```
private List<DataBean> beanList = new ArrayList<>();
private ListView listView;

private void showJSON(String response) {

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
    try {
        String lnumber;
        String violation;
        String datetime;

        DataBean dataBean = new DataBean();
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            lnumber = jsonObject.getString("lnumber");
            violation = jsonObject.getString("violation");
            dataBean.setLnumber(lnumber);
            dataBean.setViolation(violation);
            beanList.add(dataBean);
        }
        MyAdapter myAdapter = new MyAdapter(beanList,MainActivity.this);
        listView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: This works. But it only displays the last value on the JsonArray on the textviewResult with the violation "NO HELMET" . What I need to do is display both using listview but I dont know how to do one. Care to help further? Btw, Thanks!

Comment: Didn't see the edit before posting my first comment but let's nevermind the datetime key. I omitted it now

Comment: I'm very sorry. But I haven't created an adapter yet. Only made a ListView in my xml file and itemview but I dont know how to use them and populate my listview.

Comment: You can check it .

Comment: What layout do you mean @ the getView method on adapter? The layout of the activity? And also what do you mean by the `text.setText(dataBean.getLnumber() + dataBean.getViolation());` do you mean the textviewResult by this one? Again, Thank you very much!

Comment: You can look at [Using-a-BaseAdapter-with-ListView](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-a-BaseAdapter-with-ListView)

Answer (score 0):

so you want to fetch the json from the php script u have.
use AsyncDataClass to fetch json from your php script and as you are new to programming first read about AsyncDataClass and then try to print the json you fetched from the script using Log.d("","") then proceed to next step.

Comment: I can't seem to use Asynctask as  I am posting a variable for the php query and the response is the query encoded above.

Comment: u have a php script which is returning a json data, right?

Comment: Yes. `[{"lnumber":"2","violation":"2"},{"lnumber":"2","violation":"No Helmet"}]` here it is.

Comment: in which class have you written the above android code?

Comment: in showJSON method. But currently on the pasted code, it only works if my query returns a single row of result. With my question is, How can I get the jsonarray with 2 or more values and parse it into android and put it  into a listview?

Comment: have u seen what the "response" prints, try doing that and see what u have!

Comment: Currently, Yes. I made a toast and the toast contains the jsonArray Values `[{"lnumber":"2","violation":"2"},{"lnumber":"2","violation":"No Helmet"}]`

Comment: `private int returnParsedJsonObject(String result) {

        JSONObject resultObject = null;
        int returnedResult = 0;
        try {
            resultObject = new JSONObject(result);
            returnedResult = resultObject.getInt("success");
            cat = resultObject.getString("message");
            System.out.println("Returned Result is: " + returnedResult);
            System.out.println("Category of the User is :" + cat);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return returnedResult;
    } `      try using this